# path to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

It is no problem to use Html.ActionLink in a View to obtain the right path to a controller action. I am just wondering whether this is also possible in other layers (e.g. controller). I am asking this because I am generating an `<ul>` recursively with some data access to render a 'link tree structure'. Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller you can use UrlHelper to create url.

```
string html = string.Empty;
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
string edit = url.Action(Constants.action_Edit, Constants.ctrl_myController, new { someId });
html += "<a href=\"" + edit + "\">Edit</a> ";
```

This would create a string with html link inside. In the example I use constants to give correct action and controller, but it could of course be a "normal" string.

Let me know if you need more scenarios

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Just curious why are you using string html = string.Empty rather than string html = "" is this better practise?

Comment: @csetzkorn Jeff has a pretty good article on this subject http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html

Comment: @csetzkorn Well, it seems that there is a performance gain using that one, but I think most important thing is that what ever you use ("", own constant, string.Empty etc.), use it always in that project with your colleagues. It's much more pleasing to read code that has consistent programming style